# My fork of Uniswap will not show my liquidity pools

Tags: ethereum, solidity

How to recreate problem:
Go to this build...
https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmYv2TAkFNcDGG5jj9TT4G2qpVubgVP2NgHNoqn2wB71CR/build/#/swap

*DO NOT USE THIS IN MAINNET-ONLY RINKEBY

Click on the "pool" tab on the navbar after connecting your web3 enabled wallet such as metamask (make sure that your network is set to rinkeby, I only deployed contracts to that testnet!), and create a pool by clicking on "add liquidity" or "create".

The interface should let you go through with the transaction so make sure you have some test ETH on hand. The contracts created from that transaction will produce "Sushi LP Tokens"(Again not real ones, that just what I set the name to be so that it would be easily recognized.)I made sure to replace all of the contract addresses precompiled in the frontend interface with my own contracts that are listed below, even the uniswap/sdk mods.

The problem that I am having specifically is that the pool doesn't show up on the list of pairs in the modal as it usually does if you have used uniswap before. The strange thing is that it will show pools that I created on the live uniswap site using the rinkeby network.

I even created an init code hash just as instructed in this tutorial:https://blockchain.news/wiki/how-to-build-an-uniswap-exchange

I apologize in advance if this is not the correct way, place, or time to ask for help, but here I am, I am willing to work with anyone that knows how to set this up correctly.

Github:https://github.com/DarriusAlexander/uniswap-interface

My reputation is not very high so please refer to this reddit post that I created to get the contract address and metadata links.

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/n0hegy/please_helpi_forked_uniswap_for_a_personal/